# MobileMe services has stopped working message in Outlook 2006

Tags: icloud, iphone, windows, calendar

I have Windows 7 and use Microsoft Office Outlook 2006 and every time that I open it pops up a screen that says mobile me services has stopped working.

I use iCloud to merge my contacts and calendar from my iPhone 4S. What can I do to stop this from happening.  Should I uninstall iCloud and reinstall it?  What suggestions do you have?  I want to keep icloud.  If I delete mobile me will it delete icloud?

Comment: There's no such thing as Outlook 2006.

Answer (score 1):

- Delete mobile me account on the iPhone
- Add MobileMe account, but when prompted to activate "Find My iPhone" feature, keep it inactive.
- Once MobileMe account has been setup on your phone, proceed to activate the "Find My iPhone" feature.